# Teamspeak3 Server on Windows server starting different if other user starts it

Tags: windows, teamspeak

I have a TS3 server running on a Windows server. When the computer reboots we manually restart the TS3 server by logging in (it's in the Autorun). Howether, as different users log in on the Windows server the TS3 server looks different. It seems like Teamspeak does store different Serverlayouts (channels) and different permissions for each user on the Windows server...

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to want to make sure that the Teamspeak 3 server always runs as the same user.

This would be most easily achieved by running the server as a Windows service. I would recommend having a look at the [Teamspeak 3 Service Wrapper](http://addons.teamspeak.com/directory/tools/miscellaneous/Teamspeak-3-Service-Wrapper.html).

Comment: how does that work?

Comment: I mean, I have to specify a user when installing?? Which one would i choose??

Comment: @Urinprobe - Have you read the manual?

Comment: @Urinprobe: Either you create a new account specifically for the service, use your own account or use the SYSTEM account (if that is possible).

Comment: If I use my own account, will it still start when someone else loggs in instead of me?

Comment: @Urinprobe: It should be started as a service, when Windows starts. It just uses your account. You don't need to be logged in.

Comment: Well, I tried the installation, but it keeps failing due to some rights not working out. When I try starting the installer using run as administrator I get a filenotfound error from the system32 folder. The installer seems to look for the wrapper there?

Comment: @Urinprobe: What filenotfound error?

Comment: System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4157/discussion-between-oliver-salzburg-and-urinprobe)